# REGEX with letters and underscores in SPARQL

Tags: regex, sparql

in my SPARQL I have the following bind

```
BIND(STRAFTER(?ng, "tilastot_") AS ?subj)
```

It worked when I had string "tilastot_teul" in "?ng" and I needed to set the ending "teul" into "?subj"

But if there are several underscores in "?ng" (like "tilastot_luke_yri_teul") I'll need regex to extract the string after the last underscore. I tried the following:

```
BIND(STRAFTER(?ng, regex(?ng,([a-z]*_)*) AS ?subj)
```

But jena-fuseki UI didn't accept it. Can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`replace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace):

```
BIND(replace(?ng, ".*_", "") AS ?subj)
```

The `.*_` pattern matches any zero or more chars as many as possible, and then a `_` char, and  as the replacement argument is an empty string, the matched text is removed, and all you get is the substring after last `_`.

Note: if there is no `_` in the string, the output is the input string, as it was, intact.

Comment: Great thaks, it works !